# HDD led blinking without writes, why?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, ramdisk

I bought refurbished Dell laptop with SSD and began worried about SSD life etc, especially when I saw how Chrome writes cache (hdd led blinks) every time when I load a page.

What I did, [based on this article](http://yktoo.com/en/blog/post/233):

1. added mount options `noatime,nodiratime,commit=60` to **/** and **/home** mount points
2. moved **/tmp** to RAM and then moved Chrome cache dir to **/tmp**

All looks fine except one thing, now I observe HDD LED blinks every ~15-20 sec, series with 3-4 blinks, even without any visible user activities (I mean no browser or other apps started). So I [installed **iotops**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216594/investigate-disk-writes-further-to-find-out-which-process-writes-to-my-ssd) and checked, but there are no writes, one write that I see in report is iotop's.

There is no optical drive etc, only SSD and this behavior started after I moved caches to RAM.

Any ideas please? it makes me a little insane.

---

**UPD:** My mistake that used `iotops` without `--accumulate` option and tried only get report from a file, nothing in file but in live output `iotops --accumulate` I see:

```
532 be/4 develope      0.00 B    700.00 K  0.00 %  0.01 % chrome [BrowserBlocking]
  431 be/3 root          0.00 B    676.00 K  0.00 %  0.04 % [jbd2/sda6-8]
 5554 be/4 develope      0.00 B    536.00 K  0.00 %  0.01 % chrome [BrowserBlocking]
 5605 be/4 develope      0.00 B    464.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % chrome [Chrome_SyncThre]
 5559 be/4 develope      0.00 B    196.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % chrome [BrowserBlocking]
 5534 be/4 develope      0.00 B    128.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % chrome [Chrome_FileThre]
 5556 be/4 develope      0.00 B     92.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % chrome [Chrome_HistoryT]
```

So there is still Chrome issues that have to be resolved.

---

**upd:** thanks @acejavelin, now I use only noatime in mount options.

**Results (subjective)**

I moved back Chrome cache from /tmp to ~/.cache/google-chrome. LED still blinks, but not so often as before, also you can take a look on this article. I decided to train my mind to ignore blinks (or maybe will just paint it with black marker) and do backups of course :)

Comment: BTW, noatime is inclusive of nodiratime, the statement is redundant. With commit at 60, the system will commit writes on 1 minute intervals (not really necessary with modern SSD drives). The hard drive activity light could be lighting for a read process as well. To be honest, other than basic modifications (noatime, vm.swappiness=1), most changes for SSD that people recommend are outdated and don't apply to modern SSD drives in a normal desktop environment.

Comment: many thanks for info, now I read more about noatime/nodiratime/commit and will cnange my options. Yes, I know about many outdated advices, just it is my first SSD (yeah), new knowledge, experience etc. :)

Comment: No problem... I just think your expectation of never, or rarely, seeing the HD activity light is unrealistic. Remember the HD activity light flashes with either read or write activity, and often is a single LED for the entire SATA or IDE bus, not just the hard drive. You can always use 'sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX' to see the status of your drive, or some distros like Mint have a tool built into the GUI to see this information.

Comment: yes, blinks on read/write of course, I was just focused on writes when wrote the question. Interesting thing, during these 4 hours I do not touched laptop and iotops shows that Chrome processes wrote >300M ...

Comment: Could always switch to FireFox and turn off the cache... :)

Comment: I tried, same things with FF :) Also, unfortunately FF is not useful for me (I really tried to use it during laptop->laptop migration)

Comment: Maxthon is a great alternative, haven't tried it in awhile but has many of the features of Chrome, not sure if it's the ones you need though.